# Guid.NewGuid.toString Javascript error

Tags: javascript, guid, identifier

I am having JavaScript error when I use Guid.NewGuid.toString(). Here is my code...

I have created the instance of my control and add that control to my invoicePlaceHolder and assign unique id to that control by using NewGuid.

I get Javascript error: "Expected identifier" on GUID line. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
Dim objnewinvoiceinfocontrol As InvoiceDetail = CType(LoadControl("invoicedetail.ascx"), InvoiceDetail)

            invoicePlaceHolder.Controls.AddAt(0, objnewinvoiceinfocontrol)
            objnewinvoiceinfocontrol.APLogId = id
            objnewinvoiceinfocontrol.InvoiceNumber = inumber
            objnewinvoiceinfocontrol.InvoiceDate = idate
            objnewinvoiceinfocontrol.Amount = iamount
            objnewinvoiceinfocontrol.ID = Guid.NewGuid.ToString().Replace("-", String.Empty)
```

Comment: I'm seeing VB.NET yet you are mentioning JavaScript, something isn't lining up. And why are you assigning an ID of a control to a GUID anyway?

Comment: i am just trying to assign unique ID to my control. If I don't then I get server error "Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.|An entry with the same key already exists.|"

Comment: Let me ask you this. What is debug value of the ID when you hit that line.  If it is null then it could be a parsing issue.

Comment: No, it never be NULL. It always assigns unique value i.e., 3188baf8ac8e4a60b55b82837831fd1b. I don't see any server side error. It is just a small icon at the bottom of my IE with exclamation mark (yellow color). By clicking, it gives a message "Expected Identifier".

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any javascript, so the possibility of figuring out why you are getting a javascript error is pretty slim.  Also, there is hardly ever a good reason to dynamically create controls the way you are doing.  Use a repeater and bind it to a View-Model collection that represents the data that you are passing to the control.  What ever is happening on your client side will probably not be an issue if the coding is done properly, and the controls are managed by ASP.NET instead of trying to handle all the details on post back in the code behind.